# Kafka consumer failing due to nulls for value serializer

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, apache-kafka-streams, heroku-postgres, kafka-python

I have a Kafka consumer reading from a producer, but sometimes upon a record deletion from a table, null values get picked up by the consumer resulting in NoneType error message in the value serializer. How do I rewrite this 'value_serializer=lambda x loads(x.decode('utf-8'))' to check for None or Nulls. Note this is using Kafka stream from a postgresql database.

```
 consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        topic,
        bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
        auto_offset_reset='earliest',
        value_serializer=lambda x loads(x.decode('utf-8'))
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the null check in the value_serialiser as well

```
lambda x: None if not x else loads(x.decode('utf-8')
```

Entire modified code:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    topic,
    bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    value_serializer=lambda x: None if not x else loads(x.decode('utf-8'))
)
```